# Effectively final and happens before

Tags: java

I can create an effectively final variable in Java like this:

```
MyOtherClass myEffectivelyFinalObject = //...
return new MyClass() {

    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        myEffectivelyFinalObject.doSomething();
    }
}
```

My question is, do I get the same "happens-before" relationship as when I do the following:

```
MyOtherClass myEffectivelyFinalObject = //...
return new MyClass() {

    private final MyOtherClass innerReference = myEffectivelyFinalObject;

    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        innerReference.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Am I guaranteed that `myEffectivelyFinalObject` is thread visible?

Comment: No, you do not. Effectively final is merely a compiler construct to allow the usage of variables in closures. Actually final provides many thread safety guarantees. The reason you could not use non-final variables in closures was never to do with happens before - you are conflating two orthogonal concepts.

Comment: @Boris, Citation needed for "never to do with happens before". It is immensely useful if JVM could ensure the variable assignment happens-before the closure starts running in another thread.